# Allowed memory size of bytes exhausted on bind_result

Tags: php, mysql

I've had a dynamic query that is built by union smaller queries. I use union because I need to get data from a few tables in too one big list. The tables have much in common but I still need the data in seperate tables. Therefore I thought this solution seemed to be the best one.
This have worked good so far but today I added some more queries and now it's broken and it gives me this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 150994936 bytes)`

The error refers to this function:

```
function selectResults($stmt){
    $parameters = array();
    $results = array();

    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while ( $field = $meta->fetch_field() ) {   
     $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
    }

    //------THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS------
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);
    //--------------------------------------

    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
      $x = array();
      foreach( $row as $key => $val ) {
         $x[$key] = $val;
      }
      $results[] = $x;
    }

    return $results;

}
```

The function is called like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'pass', 'db');
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("some query");
$stmt -> execute();
$results = selectResults($stmt);
$stmt -> close();
$mysqli -> close();
```

The query can be about 1500 words, is that all too much?

Will putting all of the tables into the same one and just having one query solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried just using the newest subquery with another one and it still gave me the error. So I figured that the new subquery was the problem instead of the number of subqueries.
The new subquery had a mediumtext field where the other had a varchar. I tried switching the mediumtext to a varchar and now it works. I have no reason to use it as mediumtext so this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the memory_limit in your php config.

Comment: Would prefer to avoid changing things in the php config. Also I updated my question.

Comment: While this will fix the error, dragging 150MB around and copying it is a resource problem.  Most times,  an entire resultset is not required to be memory resident.  I think it is at least partially a  design problem.  Is there anyway to work with a partial resultset instead of the whole thing?

Comment: you can also change memory limit in the script or in htaccess (assuming httpd.conf allows override) if you prefer not changing it in  php config

Comment: it may be a design problem or not - plenty of times, memory limit may need to be increased such as using drupal, particularly in the admin side. It also depends on how many times the code will be executed. If it is a quick and dirty import of data that will run only once for example, optimizing it may be overkill and be more expensive (in man hours) without any added benefits. If it has to scale then this is another issue. In that case, maybe a stored procedure may be the way to go... but that was beyond the scope of the original question.